# Post build check that site works correctly

Tags: jenkins

I have deploy job, and I need to check that after build my site works correctly (no 404 or internal error) return status 200, any ideas how to do it?

Comment: HTTP Request Plugin helped

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

What I would do is something like this:

Wrap your deploy script in, say, a *bash* script that exits on error and calls your deploy script and then calls another script which checks your site.

If all you want to check for is a 200 status code, you wouldn't even need a separate script for that. Just have the wrapper script call *curl* and then check the result, returning an error code if it's not 200, so that the *Jenkins* build will fail.